# How to start a socket.io server in a dojo project

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, dojo

I'm trying to start a server socket in a nodejs dojo project but I don't know how and where,

I created a normal function that creates an express server and uses it for the socket server.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
// Express creates a server for you and starts it
var server = app.listen(4000);
console.log("start listening");

var io = require('socket.io')(app);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
       console.log("connection of client");
       socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
       socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
              console.log(data);
   });
});
```

I'm expecting to have to see the logs ( start listening, the connection of client ) but I'm getting nothing no logs and no errors or warnings.

Comment: You will see the log when your client will connect to the socket. Are you connecting the client and still not seeing the logs..?

Answer (score 0):

You may get the simple solution and basic infro [Socket.io - Documentation](https://socket.io/docs/#Sending-and-getting-data-acknowledgements) I try my best to illustarte the simple socket example over here. Assume that you are working on localhost.

server.js file:

```
    var express = require("express");
    var app = require("express")();
    var http = require("http");
    var server = http.createServer(app);
    var port = 3000;
    var io = require('socket.io')(server);

    io.on("connection", function(socket) {
        console.log("Connection established");
        socket.on('privatechatroom',function(data){
              io.emit('res',{mes:"you are added"})
        }
    }
    server.listen(port, function () {
        console.log('URL: NODE Server up and running at %s port', port);
    });
```

Client.js:

```
var socket = io.connect("localhost:3000");
socket.emit('privatechatroom');
socket.on('res', function(data){
        console.log("response getting");
    });
```